# clone docker images from local server?

Tags: docker

I was wondering if there was a way to clone images from a local server.

The servers running containers will be hosted behind a bandwidth constrained connection.   It would be great if there was a way to pull given containers for one server and then pull from that initial local server to update the containers on the remaining servers.

Answer (score 7):

You could pull those images you want, give hem a new tag, and put them in your own registry.

For instance, let's say you pulled down the official registry image and stood it up at myregistry.internal.mycompany.com.  Now, if you wanted to have a CentOS image available for all of your servers but didn't want to pull them all from the official repo (incurring the bandwitch charges) then you could pull a CentOS image (let's say centos:latest - docker pull centos) and then give that image a new tag, like this:

`docker tag centos:latest myregistry.internal.mycompany.com/centos:latest`

Now from your other servers you just pull 'myregistry.internal.mycompany.com/centos:latest'

Setting up your own repo is really easy as a docker container itself.  You can pull the image and learn more at https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/registry/

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a few options.  If what you actually want to manage is *images* rather than *containers*:

1. You could set up a private Docker registry, and then push to/pull from that local repository.  This may ultimately be the easiest if that is something that you want to do fairly often, because you're just using standard `docker push`/`docker pull` commands.
2. You could use `docker save` to save images on one server and `docker load` to load the images on another server.

If you are actually trying to move *containers* around:

1. You could use `docker export` on one server and `docker import` on another server.

Comment: Thanks,  I might setup a local registry,  the images are located in a private registry in a different location, but I remember it being a bit time consuming to setup.   Will read up on the import/export as well, wasn't aware that existed, thanks.